# setData is very slow

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview, qsqltablemodel

I'm trying to optimize a method from a program I developed.

Basically, it's a GUI (I use the PyQt library) displaying informations. Informations are stored in a sqlite database. I use a QSqlTableModel and a QTableview to display these informations. It is a very common combination.

One of the field in the database is a boolean, called "new". The purpose of the method I want to optimize is to set this boolean to 0.

Here is the method:

```
def markOneRead(self, element):

    """Slot to mark an article read"""

    print("\n")
    print("start markoneread")
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    # Get the QTableView object (I have several)
    table = self.liste_tables_in_tabs[self.onglets.currentIndex()]

    # Save the current selected line
    line = table.selectionModel().currentIndex().row()

    print("before bdd change")
    elapsed_time = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time
    print(elapsed_time)

    # Change the data in the model
    # The 12th column is the field "new". I write 0
    # !!!!! Very long action
    table.model().setData(table.model().index(line, 12), 0)

    print("before searchbutton")
    elapsed_time = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time
```

And the output is something like this:

```
before bdd change
0:00:00.000141
before searchbutton
0:00:03.064438
```

So basically, this line:

```
table.model().setData(table.model().index(line, 12), 0)
```

Takes 3 seconds to perform. That's very long, I'm just updating an item in the database, it shouldn't be that long. My database has 25000 items, but I don't think it changes something.

EDIT:
Maybe it's because the model performs the change immediately, and try to reload all the data ?

Do you have an idea about how to solve this issue ?

EDIT 2:

Actually, the problem comes from the reloading of the data. If I change the editStrategy of the model:

```
model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
```

Now it doesn't take 3 seconds anymore, but the view is not updated, new is still set to 1, after the call to the method.

So I wonder if there is a way to "reload" only one item, one index, after a model change ?

Comment: How long does it take to execute an update statement on the database to update the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps this helps:

with:

```
index = table.model().index(line, 12)
table.model().dataChanged.emit(index,index)
```

or:

```
table.model().dataChanged.emit(table.model().index(line, 12),table.model().index(line, 12))
```

you can define the items affected by  changes
see [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged).

By `table.model().dataChanged`-signal the automatical update or repaint after `table.model.setData()` should be limited to the area defined by two indices representing the top-left and bottom-right child. If both indices are identical, only one item is affected.

Comment: I don't think I understand. You basically make a copy of the index containing the "new" boolean, and you emit a signal on it ?

Comment: @Rififi: He emits the `dataChanged` signal with a range of a single cell to tell Qt to refresh only this cell (instead of the whole table).

Comment: One last question however: what could I do if the repaint is not performed ? How can I force it ?

Comment: Found the solution. For future me:         table.viewport().update()

Comment: curious: i thought, dataChanged-signal initiates an update of the view. with table.update(index) you can update only one cell.

Answer (score 0):

`QSqlTableModel` is very convenient but it's not magic. My guess is that executing the update statement takes most of the time. Try to update the a few rows manually and see how long that goes.

If this is slow as well, then you probably need an index on the table so sqlite can locate rows more quickly.

Comment: Nope actually, updating an item in the database is very quick. Reloading the data however, is very slow. Because what I didn't tell you is I modified the default behavior of the model, to load all the data at once (more practical for sorting, etc). So each time a change was made on the database, I had to reload all the database. @a_manthey_67's solution is great, because I only update one item in the view.